# Vaadin Form TextField multiline caption

Tags: java, web, textfield, vaadin

I have an Form with many TextField's (Vaadin), each one have very long caption.

Can i make TextField's caption multiline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can. Can you use TextArea instead?

Update:
Define a custom style in your style.css:

```
.v-caption-multiline {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

And then use in in your code to separate the lines by \n:

```
TextField t = new TextField("A very long caption\nA very long caption ");
t.addStyleName("multiline");
```

Comment: TextArea allow multiline caption?, i mean caption, not value

Comment: No, the caption is the same, inherited from AbstractTextField. Maybe it will work if you put the TextField inside a Panel.

Comment: it works, but field height does not allow TextField display correctly

Comment: That depends on how you arranged and sized your containers.

Answer (score 1):

In Vaadin 7, the Panel caption excepts HTML.

Example, <sub>subscript</sub> and <br/> commands.

I don't know about version prior to 7.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get multi-line captions is to use a GridLayout and emulate captions with Labels.

Comment: I replace TextField with Panel, contains formatted Label (caption) and TextField without caption.